# Where can I buy piranha in UK?

Tags: fish, shopping

I've heard that piranha is delicious (for some) and I'm curious about it. I live in Surrey, UK. I've checked various supermarkets (Tesco, Sainsburuy's, ...) and found nothing. Even Amazon says "No results for piranha in Grocery". General online searches seem to be about piranha as a dangerous animal, a pet, etc., but not about piranha as food. Also, buying a pet fish to eat seems rather expensive, I expect because live fish is more expensive to keep and transport to a shop.

So, is it possible to buy piranha as food in UK (preferably Surrey), how and where?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you should at least look for it in specialized fishmongers, not supermarkets.

Comment: Since piranhas are native species from Amazon (the region, not the company), I'm not sure it's commercially sold anywhere as food... Specially so far away as the UK

Comment: Ask [this guy](https://apnews.com/article/c125f4b2d2114ca7bfe44a4276dfd63b).

Comment: There are sellers who specialise in exotic meats (from the comparatively common like kangaroo or crocodile through to rarer products). Even if one doesn't advertise piranha, I would try contacting such a place as they're likely to have the contacts to pursue an enquiry if you could promise you'd be able to pay adequately. Any regular fishmonger or food distributor is unlikely to be helpful because this is about importing a rare and perishable product.

Comment: Be aware that the fish may be available, but not by the name "piranha" (even if it is actually some species of piranha)

Comment: Besides what was said I'd try to look in Brazilian sellers or asking around in Brazil neighborhoods, since they'd be the most likely potential clients